# How to get time value using PHP same as TIMEVALUE() function in Excel

Tags: php, time

Here I have one string contain `"00:01:00"` in Excel sheet, now I will pass this string to `TIMEVALUE()` function of Excel to return 0.000694 same way I want in PHP.

Is there any function for performing this task, or any other way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 5):

An Excel timestamp is just a float where 24 hours is 1 day, so one hour is 1/24th.

Calculate the difference between the timestamp values for `00:01:00` and `00:00:00`, then divide by the number of seconds in a day

```
$x = strtotime("00:01:00");
$y = strtotime("00:00:00");

echo ($x - $y) / 86400, PHP_EOL;
```